MEV from solana
I have a simple question, can we do MEV directly from a validator, as in if we run a validator with almost no delegation is it even possible?
Sorry if my question is weird im very very new into Solana

It depends what you mean by MEV.
Sandwiching, Frontrunning etc.? Not directly, you'd have to write your own searcher for this.
You can however benefit directly from others doing MEV by using the Jito Client. This allows searchers to submit bundles of transactions that the validator guarantees to execute in the provided order in exchange for some extra fees aside from the transaction fees (which is what pretty much every searcher uses to execute their transactions).

Thanks!
for "To write your own searcher" do you have any reference or document for this. I just need a kick start then I can research myself, cause Im really not sure where to start.

Yes, Jito has a docs section just for this too: https://www.jito.wtf/searchers/

You can only perform MEV if your validator is the leader, so you'll need to get enough stake delegated to get leader slots, which I think is around 50k SOL.
